# How loadUserByUsername method in Spring Security works?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have implemeted spring security in my application and the implementation of `loadUserByUsername` is like below

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String emailOrContact) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        log.info("Fetching user infromation from db");
        Optional<UserDomain> domain = userRepository.findByEmailOrContactAndIsDeleted(emailOrContact, emailOrContact,
                0);
        if (!domain.isPresent()) {

            log.error("User not found with username {}", emailOrContact);

        }

        UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
        UserDomain userDomain = domain.get();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDomain, userDetail);
        log.info("User Details {}", userDetail);
        return userDetail;
    }
```

I was checking this method execution in debug mode and found when we provide correct username and password it fetches user from database but when we provide correct username but wrong password it does not fetch record from database. I am wondering if `findByEmailOrContactAndIsDeleted` generate sql query like 
`select * from xyz table where email = 'abc@gmail.com' or contact = '9999999999' and deleted = 0`
where it is validating password and why it is not fetching record if password is wrong?

Comment: Password doesn't matter, that is validated by Spring Security after the user has been retrieved. Also your code is wrong as it breaks the contract for `UserDetailsService`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you please help me to understand what is wrong in code so that I can correct it?

Comment: If the user isn't found, a `UsernameNotFoundException` must be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

> where it is validating password and why it is not fetching record if
>   password is wrong?

Spring Security calls a `AuthenticationManager` which calls an `AuthenticationProvider` which calls a `AuthenticationService` like the one you have written. Password validation takes place in `AuthenticationProvider`. Have a look at [DaoAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.java).

If Password is wrong a `BadCredentialsException` will be thrown by the `AuthenticationProvider`.